# Database-Independent MAX() Function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'd like to calculate a MAX() value for a column.  What's the proper way to do this in sqlalchemy while preserving database independence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find aggregate functions in:

```
from sqlalchemy import func 
func.avg(...) 
func.sum(...) 
func.max(...)
```

In 0.5 you can use an ORM query like a select:

```
session.query(func.max(Table.column))
```

Comment: Is this database independent?

Comment: This was great.  Thank you, Dave.