# sqlalchemy: get max/min/avg values from a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this query:

```
mps =   (
            session.query(mps)  .filter_by(idc = int(c.idc))
                                .filter_by(idmp = int(m.idmp))
                                .group_by(func.day(mps.tschecked))
        ).all()
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to extract (with sqlalchemy) the max/min/avg value from a table...

I find this: [Database-Independent MAX() Function in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358634/database-independent-max-function-in-sqlalchemy)

But I don't know where to use this func.max/min/avg...

Can someone tell me how to do this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: wouldn't you just change the above to be `session.query(func.avg(mps.some_column)).filter...`?  i haven't tried it, or used sqlalchemy in a while, but that seems like the obvious conclusion from the link you gave.  does it not work?

Comment: It works, but than I need to call values like mps[0], and not mps.tschecked... can this be done in a different way?

Comment: `mps` is at least two different things in your code.  why are you doing that?  the results are described in the documentation http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy - you can use index, name, or a column object

Comment: Ok, now I understand this... tnx for your time/help!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following functions are available with `from sqlalchemy import func`:

- `func.min`
- `func.max`
- `func.avg`

Documentation is available [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func).

You can use them i.e. in the query() method.

Example:

```
session.query(self.stats.c.ID, func.max(self.stats.c.STA_DATE))
```

(just like you use aggregate functions in plain SQL)

Comment: You can find the [documentation for `func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) here, but you can just import it with `from sqlalchemy import func`.

Answer (score -21):

Or just use an order_by() and select the first or last element. . .